# Selenium Java returns incorrect results for element.isDisplayed

Tags: java, selenium

I am running tests using Java, Selenium & TestNG.
(selenium-server-standalone.3.8.3, Java 8 Update 151)

I am using Firefox Quantum 61.0.2 (64-bit) as browser.

I have a problem where an element I need to click on is dissappearing, and I want to log an error when this occurs.

Unfortunately, `element.isDisplayed` returned true when to element is clearly no there.

What makes diagnosing this problem difficult is that clicking the 'invisible' element actually works, but still leads to unpredictable results.

How can I get the correct answer?

This is an example of code used:

```
public static boolean isElementDisplayed(String className, String textToFind, String htmlElement,
        WebDriver driver) {

    // String className = "map-popup-button";
    // String textToFind = "icon-structure-tree";
    // String htmlElement = "button";

    List<WebElement> elements = Common.findElementsUsingHtmlXpathClass(driver, htmlElement, className);
    Common.myPrint(thisClass + " elements count: " + elements.size());
    String text = "";
    String attr = "";
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        // select an element
        if(!Common.retryingIsElementDisplayed(element)) {
            Common.scrollIntoView(element, driver);
        }
        if (Common.retryingIsElementDisplayed(element)) {
            text = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
            if (text != "") {
                text = text.trim();
                if (text.contains(textToFind)) {
                    Common.myPrint(thisClass + " innerHTML: " + text);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            attr = Common.getAllAttributes(element, driver);
            if (attr.contains(textToFind)) {
                Common.myPrint(thisClass + " attr: " + text);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and that retryingIsElementDisplayed function:

```
public static boolean retryingIsElementDisplayed(WebElement element) {
    // myPrint(thisClass + " retryingIsElementDisplayed...");
    boolean result = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while (attempts < 2) {
        try {
            result = element.isDisplayed();

            break;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            int errorCode = 1533564891;
            Common.myPrint(thisClass + " error code: " + errorCode +" Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Common.myPrint(thisClass + " *** INFO ONLY *** ");
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Tests have shown that this problem occurs after using javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element); on a different element. This is scrolling my logo up out of view. When I manually scroll back down, the element is no longer visible (but still - presumably - present in the DOM)

This is HTML of the element I am looking for:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Vector_Smart_Object_xA0_Image_1_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 50;" xml:space="preserve">
```

```
 .st0{fill:#FFF;}
</style>
<g>
    <polygon class="st0" points="119.2,12.4 126.3,12.4 126.3,31.3 138.4,31.3 138.4,37.5 119.2,37.5  "></polygon>
    <polygon class="st0" points="140.3,12.4 147.3,12.4 147.3,31.3 159.4,31.3 159.4,37.5 140.3,37.5  "></polygon>
    <polygon class="st0" points="202.1,12.4 197.1,21.5 192,12.4 184,12.4 193.6,28.3 193.6,37.4 200.7,37.4 200.7,28.3 210.2,12.4     "></polygon>
    <path class="st0" d="M172.7,11.7c-7.4,0-13.5,6-13.5,13.3s6.2,13.3,13.5,13.3c7.4,0,13.3-6,13.3-13.3s-6.2-13.3-13.5-13.3    M172.6,31.6c-3.5,0-6.3-3-6.3-6.7s2.8-6.7,6.3-6.7c3.5,0,6.3,3,6.3,6.7S176.1,31.6,172.6,31.6"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M107.2,12.2h-6.7L89.8,37.5h7.3l2-4.6l9.4,0.1l1.8,4.5h7.4L107.2,12.2z M101.3,27.1l2.6-6.5l2.6,6.5H101.3z"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `text != ""` doesn't look right.

Comment: That is not the question. text!= "" works perfectly, and tests whether a string is returned or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java - YMMV.

Comment: still not the question. the function returns true when I think it should not!

Comment: As you said, the element is disappearing. Did you wait enough time before call `isElementDisplayed()`?  If not,  maybe before the first 100ms, the element is still visible and the 1st  iteration of `while(attempts <2 )` happened at before 100ms, so loop break and `true` returned.

Comment: Does you while loop go for the second attempt? Also there might be a logical error. If I am not wrong:  If element is not visible, You got false. If you have false, then you scrollIntoView?

Comment: No. The function retryingIsElementDisplayed was written to overcome Stale Element Reference exceptions.

Comment: @SteveStaple I think yong might be right. Maybe it is a issue with element did not disappear yet. Please try to give 2-3 Thread.sleep(5000) and check if element.isDisplayed() between them.

Comment: Deryl - "Also there might be a logical error. If I am not wrong: If element is not visible, You got false. If you have false, then you scrollIntoView" - this will scroll the element into view if that is possible, but it does not affect the end result.

Comment: Deryl " Maybe it is a issue with element did not disappear yet" - this is not what I am testing. My  retryingIsElementDisplayed was written to overcome Stale Element Reference exceptions

Comment: Your question is actually about element being displayed or not and the result of isDisplayed(). Before You said, that the element is disappearing. If it is not done instantly, "Wait" is the first thing You should use to check states of element every few seconds.

Comment: Deryl. The element in question is not meant to disappear. This is a bug I am trying to identify. It does not disappear whilst this actual function is running. It occurs due to other actions during the tests.

Comment: Is there a difference in html code when that element appears or disappears? Can you share the html for both states.

Comment: @SteveStaple You might want to try run test in debug mode. Set some breakpoints in which You will have a chance to manually search for element with the selector You have. Maybe it wll give You (and us :) ) some more informations.

Comment: @theGuy - the page source is identical in both cases!

Comment: Just to be clear, `.isDisplayed()` has nothing to do with whether the element is on the screen or not... it has to do with whether it's not visible, e.g. display: none, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this way harder than it needs to be. You are passing `String`s used to locate elements around instead of using the Selenium-supplied `By` locator class.

A simple example given the HTML element you want to find.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Vector_Smart_Object_xA0_Image_1_" ...>
```

We can find this element using a simple `By.id()` locator, e.g.

```
By svgElementLocator = By.id("Vector_Smart_Object_xA0_Image_1_");
```

Now you can pass this into a function that checks to see if it's displayed or not.

```
public static boolean isElementDisplayed(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
    try {
        return driver.findElement(locator).isDisplayed();
        break;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Because you are no longer passing around a `WebElement`, you don't have to worry about StaleElementExceptions, etc. and your code is much simpler. You can call this like

```
bool result = isElementDisplayed(driver, svgElementLocator);
```

Just to be clear, `.isDisplayed()` has nothing to do with whether the element is on the screen or not... it has to do with whether it's not visible, e.g. display: none, etc. See [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--).

> Is this element displayed or not? This method avoids the problem of having to parse an element's "style" attribute.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC, I will try this, but it does not solve my problem. It would still tell me that the element is displayed when I can't see it.

Comment: I did not intend to downvote your response, but it is still not a solution to my problem. i.e it is displayed, but not visible.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? Or at least some sample page where we can see similar behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the same **web element** in a **list.**

Demonstration code would look like this :

```
List<WebElement> errorMsg = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath for error msg"));
            if(errorMsg.size()>0) {
                //do something when error occurs 
            }
            else {
                //your script knows , that there is no error msg.
            }
```

Comment: That is not the question either

Comment: Since you have mentioned that, `element.isDisplayed` is returning true, It would return true if the element is present in DOM, irrespective of whether it is visible in UI or not.

Comment: That is the crux of the question. isDisplayed returns true when it is not.

Comment: How did you check the DOM ?

Comment: `isDisplayed` returns true if element is visible, otherwise it would return false. But `isDiaplayed` throws the error if element is not exist. Element existence is the prerequisite for `isDisplayed` method

Comment: Rajagopalan  - that is not the question!Tthe element exists and shows isDisplayed = true, but it is not actually displayed.

Comment: How did you check the DOM ? - I didn't. I used element.isDiaplayed as stated.

Comment: That's what. You could use `findElements` instead of `findElement`, and store a web element in a list. then if the size of list is greater than 1 , that means there is an error message.

Comment: cruisepandey. That is not the answer.  I am already using findElements.

Comment: @SteveStaple Webdriver view point is different fromyour view point, for an example, you could scroll this screen and see some elements, before you scroll this page, those elements are invisible for you, but for webdriver, it's not. When you reply me, you need to add@ infront of my name, otherwise I would not be notified.

Comment: Instead of `result = element.isDisplayed();` line you will have to use `findElements`
` , Not sure if you are doing the same thing.

Comment: @cruisepandey. I am doing findElements before element.isDisplayed?

Comment: @Rajagapolan - scrollIntoView is not my issue either. Apparently it can scroll an element into view & it is still not there!

Comment: @Rajagopalan I believe what he means is, the Element is within the DOM, so it has been found.. But the Element is actually `display: none` and so `isDisplayed()` should return false. It could also be that the bounding box of the element is off the top or bottom of the window, and should return false. It could also be that the element is within the window box, but has a parent which has `overflow: hidden` so the element is not actually visible to the human eye, and so should return `false`.

Comment: I guess I should close this issue, as it is obviously not solvable. The html in both cases is identical. (between scrolling manually or doing javascript scrollIntoView using the Web Console. Our dev team tells me they are using a plug in with the scroll bar, so my problem likely lies there. I will just have to be content with a workaround.

Comment: Two questions: exactly what KIND of element is this, and what version of Selenium are you using? (sorry if you already stated and I missed it).  I do recall there being an issue with either checkboxes or radio buttons not returning a correct answer for .isDisplayed() in earlier versions of Selenium.  I don't know that if it was ever fixed.  I know that I had to instead code work-arounds to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Bill Hileman - I have added HTML of the element in question to the question.